# How to cover the code inside the for()

Tags: unit-test

What do I need to set contactsFromQ_List2 and   completeContacts_List2 to in order to cover the code in the two for() loops?

This is the values of the two lists.

```
    contactsFromQ_List2 = [Select contact__r.Training_Period__c,Name,  Contact__c, Contact_Name__c, a.Supervisor_Name__c, 
                                                                        a.RecordTypeId, 
                                                                        a.Coordinator_Name__c, a.Active__c 
                                                                        From Additional_Contact_Role__c a 
                                                                        Where a.RecordTypeId = :sRTId
                                                                        AND Contact__c != Null
                                                                        AND CALENDAR_YEAR(a.From_Date__c) = :yearChosen
                                                                        AND Contact__c IN :currentContactIds_Set
                                                                        AND contact__r.Training_Period__c = :TRAINING_PERIOD
                                                                        ];

    completeContacts_List2 = [Select Name, Type_Community__c, Contact__c, Contact_Name__c, a.Supervisor_Name__c, 
                                                                        a.RecordTypeId, a.Months_in__c,   a.Id, 
                                                                        a.Coordinator_Name__c, a.Active__c 
                                                                        From Additional_Contact_Role__c a 
                                                                        Where a.RecordTypeId = :sRTId];
```

Thiis is the code I need to cover but it doesn't get into the for() loop.

```
    // Prep the contacts lists
    for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : contactsFromQ_List2){
        sp = new selectedPerson();
        sp.isSelected = true;
        sp.contactR = cr;
        completeContacts4VF_List.add(sp);
    }

    for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : completeContacts_List2){
        sp = new selectedPerson();
        sp.isSelected = false;
        sp.contactR = cr;
        completeContacts4VF_List.add(sp);
    }
```

Comment: simple answer: create test data that would be returned during for loop.
complex answer: separate methods that query data from server and do logic on it. Test those separately. In that case, your code would be able to access records, which are not in database during testing

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you give me an example based on the code I gave?

Answer (score 1):

First, these don't appear to be valid queries for `contactsFromQ`_List2 and `completeContacts`_List2. In your queries, the fields you're using can't reference variables to be returned that don't have proper object or field names.

These queries should be of type `list<Additional_Contact_Role__c>`

In the first query, examples I'm referring to would be:

```
a.Supervisor_Name__c, a.RecordTypeId, a.Coordinator_Name__c and a.Active__c
```

From Additional_Contact_Role__c a

Additional_Contact_Role__c should be the object. You shouldn't be specifying a variable `a` following that object. It makes no sense to continue that query with

```
Where a.RecordTypeId = :sRTId ... CALENDAR_YEAR(a.From_Date__c) = :yearChosen
```

Essentially, you're making self-references.

You do the same in your 2nd query with:

```
a.Supervisor_Name__c, a.RecordTypeId, a.Months_in__c, a.Id, a.Coordinator_Name__c, 
    a.Active__c From Additional_Contact_Role__c a Where a.RecordTypeId = :sRTId
```

Once you understand the above, you'll also understand that you need to create any of the records that you want to query for these Additional_Contact_Role__c records of that RecordType which contain all of the fields that are included in your query.